# How permanently access the microphone in IOS id user deny the allowing in AIR application?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder

How i access the microphone in iOS id user deny the allowing in AIR application ?

I am using AIR 3.8.

When i run in debug mode on device it prompts that Flash Debug requires microphone access.

And how i get mic if user deny to access on prompt ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. That's the entire point of the prompt — to give the user a choice in whether your app can access something that could potentially invade their privacy or harm their system. There would be no point in the prompt if you could override it.

Adobe is real big on these kinds of security tasks (after Macromedia was relatively lax) and Apple is even stricter. If the user says no, it means no. There is absolutely no way around it.

Comment: But the same time is used camera too but there is no prompt for that, camera is also part of ipad device ?

Comment: You actually do get prompted when an app tries to get an image from the device or use the camera application to take a photo or video. Not sure about using the camera within an app itself, however. I've never tested that. Either way, these restraints are Apple restrictions. They are implemented at the OS-level. There is absolutely nothing you can do about it, regardless of technology used (native, AIR, otherwise) or code written.

Comment: But this problem is only with ios 7 devices. I tested my application with ios 6 it runs perfect.

Comment: It's a new permission in iOS 7. See https://support.shazam.com/entries/26560426-Microphone-access-now-required-iOS7- about the Shazam app or http://9to5mac.com/2013/06/11/apps-have-to-ask-for-permission-to-access-the-microphone-in-ios-7/ from 9to5Mac. There is no way around it. It is required by the OS. You either get permission, or you don't get to use the microphone. That's just how it is. Nothing you can do.

Comment: Thanks  Josh Janusch, But is there any way with code to find out that user actually deny access to microphone, so that we at least show an appropriate message to user.

Comment: I was doing some searching yesterday while finding the links in my previous comment and it looks like the answer is no, unfortunately. Definitely not in AIR, at least.